# Problem with DiscriminatorValue - The abstract schema is unknown

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I must run project with JEE and EclipseLink 2.6.1. Maven successfully compiles the project, but when I put . jar on Payara and try to run it it gets problems of the type:

```
The abstract schema type 'NetServer'; is unknown. 
The state field path 'netserver.active'; cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

The problem occurs in queries with all entities with annotations @DiscriminatorValue. Entity looks like this:

**Main class (Servers) :**

```
    @Entity
    @Table("Servers")
    @DiscriminatorColumn(
        name = "SERVER_TYPE",
        discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING
    )
    @DiscriminatorValue("servers")
    public class Servers{

        @Id
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private String hostname;
        private Boolean active;
    //getters& setters
    }
```

**Netserver:**

```
        @Entity
        @DiscriminatorValue("netserver")
        public class NetServer extends Server{

        private String url;
        public Netserver();
        public Netserver(Server server){super(server);}
        //getters&setters
        }
```

And I wonder what the problem is that he throws away exceptions?

Comment: Try to add @Inheritance to the Servers class

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Turn EclipseLink logging to finest and check what is logged for the Servers and NetServer classes during deployment, as you should see entries if they get loaded by the persistence unit. I'm hoping that NetServer extends Server is a typo, as the class you are showing is "Servers"

Comment: Okej, I found a problem: entity are in jar. Eclipselink looks for jar in the directory (on war): \ WEB-INF\classes, and the jar is there in: \WEB-INF\lib. Despite the jar-file property configured in persistence.xml (in WEB-INF\classes\META-INF) it ignored properly. How can this be changed?